# if binding in knockoutjs not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I am trying to use if statement in knockoutjs with databinding:

for example this if should be false and the text in div should be hidden:

```
    <!-- this is what i am trying to get working. -->
    <div data-bind="if: little">rank : little</div>
```

My guess is this piece does not work as intended. It should return false as on start the the clickCount is 0.

```
  this.little = function(){
    return this.clickCount() > 5;
  };
```

I have pasted the code of app.js and index.html.

this is app.js

```
var ViewModel = function (){
  this.clickCount = ko.observable(0);
  this.name = ko.observable('Tabby');
  this.imgSrc = ko.observable('img/2.jpg');
  this.imgAttribution = ko.observable('http://www.flickr.com/photos/big');


  this.incrementCounter = function() {
    this.clickCount(this.clickCount() + 1);
  };


  // this is not returning false as it should.
  this.little = function(){
    return this.clickCount() > 5;
  };

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>

        <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>
        <div data-bind="text: clickCount"></div>

        <!-- this is what i am trying to get working. -->
        <div data-bind="if: little">rank : little</div>

        <img src="" alt="cute cat" data-bind="click: incrementCounter, attr:{src: imgSrc}">

    </div>
    <script src="js/lib/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a function, `little` is always true. Test `little()` instead.

Comment: Like @RoyJ stated, little is a function, and simply because it exists it evaluates to to true. A good way to debug in Knockout is to replace your `if`s with `text`s. See your code here with `little` and `little()` written out. http://codepen.io/mblarsen/pen/QyXObm

Comment: And it might be that you thought your `little` was a computed observable that's why you didn't put those `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use visible Binding of knockout

Following code will work for you:

```
    <div data-bind="visible: !little()">rank : little</div>
                            OR
    <div data-bind="visible: little()">rank : little</div>
```